# Bootstrap container, image loses alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The page i've made so far can be viewed [here](http://jsbin.com/fujozekoqama/1/).

And the HTML here: http://jsbin.com/fujozekoqama/1/edit?html

Notice what happens when you make the browser window **smaller**.

Why does the image lose alignment to the menu if they are in the same container?

Here are pictures of what I'm seeing:

**aligned**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWQeR.png

**unaligned**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HxuU.png

Comment: I don't see any loss of alignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove this from your styles, because it's affecting the responsiveness of the layout:

```
.container .navbar-default {
    min-width:640px;
    width:640px;
    }
```

and add the `.img-responsive` class to your image, like this:

```
<img class="logo img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x75">
```

and then close the first `.container` div, which is open

with these tiny changes, it will work just as you want, and your layout will be responsive (which is the whole idea after Bootstrap after all).

If you need some min-width, add it in the `.container` class, not the inner elements. For this purpose, it's always a good idea to add an additional class to re-usable classes, for example `<div class="container myMinWidth">` so you can target the `.myMinWidth` class without affecting the `.container` class, which you will need to use everywhere in Bootstrap.

And finally, unless you really need it (which you probably don't), avoid using fixed sizes in responsive layouts, if needed, try to use percentages, but make sure to check Bootstrap docs, because there are lots of built-in classes like `img-responsive` that will adjust your images like in your present situation